# code igniter database (Trying to get property of non-object) on server

Tags: codeigniter

On my local machine I access my application using

> http://localhost/index.php

on the server i publish it its

> http://myserver:8888/alias/index.php

I've updated this in code igniter config and also replicated my local database on the server. Now something screwy is happening on the server when it reaches

> $this->db->query($queryStr)->row()->ID;

I tried to manually run the query inside $queryStr and it gives me back data from the command line however when I ran it like above on the server

> $this->db->query($queryStr)->row()
>    returns an empty array

I get

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of
>   non-object
>
> Filename: models/model_mymodel.php

Am I overlooking something why is the exact same code not working on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you code to capitalization (case) errors. If your development machine is windows based, it then it does not care about case. You linux server does however.

Comment: I've run into trouble with this more than once. Now I use all lowercase for file names.

Comment: thanks alot that was one of the issue! the other issue was that it was connecting to a different database. I have two database servers running and both had the database inserted.